# No operator presets: FBX 6.1 ASCII, FBX 7.4 Binary

Tags: export, .fbx

I have no operator preset options (FBX 6.1 ASCII, FBX 7.4 Binary). I had blender 2,79 now 2.80 but no presets appear. That makes it impossible for me to export FBX with textures. I read somewhere that some file needs to be modify somewhere on the computer but it wasn't clear. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

[The .fbx ASCII format has been removed](https://developer.blender.org/T53877) in Blender 2.8, the remaining export format is the binary format. You should be able to export to the other application just as you did in Blender 2.79, except that in the older version you had to explicitly select the binary format which is now the default in 2.8. The materials need to be setup separately because .fbx can't store Cycles or Eevee materials.

In order to embed texture into the file you have to set the following two options:

1. *Path Mode* is Copy
2. *Embed Textures* is enabled

[image]

Although I haven't personally tested it, you may want to try glTF as export format because it should be able to translate textures and materials to the other software, if you use the principled shader for a PBR setup.

Comment: I don't have format options (not ASCII or any other) is that normal? The other thing I'm not intending to use this in unreal engine but in 3ds max to do Animation. Vertex Paint in 3ds max is a pain in the A**. Blender method is perfect... but not for me because a can't export anything...

Comment: @Ivan Yes as I said the export is in the binary format, because the ASCII option has been removed in Blender 2.8

Comment: Ok, then why I can't have textures exported ever?

Comment: @Ivan I've added the relevant export options.

Comment: Yes I've done that a thousand times, I select copy then select the icon to embed the textures that is on the right side the little box with papers, and then... nothing.... just the fbx without textures. This happened in 2.79 and now in 2.8.. still no solution.

Comment: @Ivan the texture is embedded in the fbx file, you won't get extra files besides that. If you want your texture as separate files, you will have to save them in the directory and then decide how you want to reference them in the fbx (relative path, absolute path, etc.)

Comment: Every time I export it, I then re-import it into 3ds max or blender, and there's nothing. I can also see that for the weight of the FBX, It weights the same as when imported. The same 1.2mb...

Comment: I've tested this before I added the information and it works. Perhaps you do something unusual in your node setup? Are the textures actual images or procedural? Have you created the texture internally, e.g. by texture painting?

Comment: These are all jpg files. Maybe the resolution is too high: 2048 by 2048?

Comment: @Ivan I don't think the resolution is limited. I'm out of ideas. I doubt I'll find out what the problem is without taking a look at the project file.

Comment: How can I send it to you?

Comment: Google Drive perhaps?

Comment: Great in a few minutes

Comment: I've found some kind of solution at last... export it as collada and then the textures do stick.... but, I really want to know what's wrong with the fbx. Here's a link to download the orginial fbx and the paint textures: https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZMsmi7ZVg55MCi4w88RezaLzN6h2J9qwWCy

Comment: Your original fbx is broken. There are no texture coordinates  and textures linked. So whatever software you used to create that file messed up.

Comment: I did it in 3ds max..... maybe I have a virus then... Dam!

Comment: @Ivan that wouldn't be likeliest explanation, could simply be a bad configuration in 3ds max or a bug.

Comment: I´ll try re-installing and re-test when I have a time window then...